# How is score calculated in Google's 15th Anniversary Doodle?

Tags: google-doodles

I just managed to make 183 points (candies) in the doodle, and now I'm trying to reproduce that score on my computer. What is the best way to hit the piñata in order to have more candies? Is there any random calculation involved?

I just tried to reproduce the same that I did to make that 183 score. Usually I try to hit the piñata with the end of the stick. At first when it balance to the right, and then when it comes to me.

Comment: I seemed to have the best results with hitting the pinata as it was swinging towards me with the end of the stick as well. I never manage to get more than 3 on the first drop though.

Comment: Are you talking about the [15th anniversary doodle](http://www.google.com/doodles/googles-15th-birthday)? If not I would say your question is off topic because it is about unreleased game.

Comment: @Blem Yes, sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to hit the piñata when it comes toward you, with the end of the stick. You have to not miss any hit (not let it swings) as shown : [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5x9HFIuBs0). If you hit perfectly with the end of the stick without missing you can achieve over 180 everytime.

According to [this article](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/7bimma) and after having inspected the source code ([Here](https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js) and [Here](http://www.google.com/doodles/js/doodle_javascript.js)), I would say that there are no random calculation of the score and the number of candy drop is based on the "speed" of the piñata and the spot of impact with the stick.

Comment: While this describes the best way to get a high score does it really answer **HOW** the score is calculated?